# Iptables down in RHEL7,3

Tags: linux

In rhel 7.3  iptables services goes down after server reboot
iptabels enabled 
IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_STOP="yes" IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_RESTART="yes" are on

Answer (score 0):

In rhel 7.3 iptables has been replaced by [firewalld](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html#sec-Introduction_to_firewalld).
However is possible to install and enable [iptables](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html#sec-Using_iptables).